# What is the meaning of $KO^{-1}(S^1)$?

Tags: vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, k-theory, topological-k-theory

I am interested in the KO-theory of the circle $S^1$. In particular $KO^{-1}(S^1)$. Using the suspension theorem and reduced $K$-theory I can easily show that
\begin{equation}
KO^{-1}(S^1) \simeq KO^{-1}(pt) \oplus KO^{-2}(pt) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2^2\,.
\end{equation}
My question is now what the interpretation is of these two $Z_2$s? I understand that they tell me that there are four different types of bundles, but is there a topological invariant that distinguishes them? For instance, can we use Stiefel-Whitney classes? Any reference where this is addressed would also be very welcome!

Comment: I used reduced $K$-theory to show $KO^{-1}(S^1) = KO^{-1}(pt) \oplus \widetilde{KO^{-1}}(S^1)$ and then the suspension theorem to simplify the last term to $KO^{-2}(pt)$. Furthermore I used $KO^{-1}(pt) = \mathbb{Z}_2 = KO^{-2}(pt)$.

Comment: Oh, I guess that is correct, but we also have $\widetilde{KO^{-2}}(pt) = KO^{-2}(pt)$, no?

Comment: Ok that is fine, but do you agree $\widetilde{KO^{-2}}(pt) = \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Why is that? The K-theory is not the complex one, but KO-theory, which doesn't have the 2-period Bott clock, but rather 8-periodic. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I think I may have said some things wrong. I am going to delete all my comments. If I figure out what I meant to say, I will write it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$KO^{-1}(S^1) \cong \widetilde{KO}^{-1}(S^1\sqcup\text{pt}) \cong \widetilde{KO}(\Sigma(S^1\sqcup\text{pt})) \cong \widetilde{KO}(S^2\vee S^1) \cong \widetilde{KO}(S^2)\oplus\widetilde{KO}(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2.$$

The generator of $\widetilde{KO}(S^2)$ is the equivalence class of non-spin bundles which is represented by $\mathcal{O}(1) \to \mathbb{CP}^1$, viewed as a real rank two bundle over $S^2$.

The generator of $\widetilde{KO}(S^1)$ is the equivalence class of non-orientable bundles which is represented by $\gamma_1 \to \mathbb{RP}^1$, viewed as a real rank one bundle over $S^1$.

Comment: Great! Thanks @Michael. Right, so is it correct to say that the topological invariant for each of these two is second and first, Stiefel-Whitney class, respectively?

Comment: Yes. The generator of $\widetilde{KO}(S^2)$ has non-zero second Stiefel-Whitney class, while the generator of $\widetilde{KO}(S^1)$ has non-zero first Stiefel-Whitney class.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!